# Kafka Serialization of hashmap to json in java

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, hashmap

In configure method of kafka serializer -

```
void configure( java.util.Map< java.lang.String, ? >config, boolean is key)
```

Could I please get the elaboration on the `'config'` parameter and the `'iskey'` and how to use it while serializing a hashmap to JSON object ?

Comment: Which `JsonSerializer`? Kafka doesn't provides one. Are you talking about the one in spring? Looking at the code is usually the easiest way, as some other serialisers for Json just ignore the `isKey` parameter.

Comment: @Augusto Thank you. For sending JSon objects to  kafka, Is Jsonserializer better or  kafka java client(this doesnt use spring)